# Get Current Day in Milliseconds In Java

Tags: java, datetime

This is probably a very simple matter, but I would like to get the current day in milliseconds; that is, the Unix Timestamp at midnight of the current day. I know that I could do it by having

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - new DateTime().millisOfDay().getMillis;
```

But, is there a way to do this simpler? Like, is there a way to do this is one line without subtracting?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607864/how-can-i-get-two-midnights-from-given-instant); ignore that it is asking for "midnight tomorrow" too; the answers tell you how to get "midnight today". However: note that you should use the start of the day, not midnight: midnight doesn't always exist.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm a little intrigued by that... when can midnight not exist? DST and leap years/seconds wouldn't interfere with it.

Comment: @Sneftel e.g. Asia/Gaza on 26th March 2016 - doesn't have midnight, because DST starts at midnight, and so the time jumps straight to 1am.

Comment: Have a look at `GregorianCalendar`. You can set the time zone and it has a method `computeTime()` which is the ms offset from the epoch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in Java 8 like this:

```
ZonedDateTime startOfToday = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long todayMillis1 = startOfToday.toEpochSecond() * 1000;
```

Or in any Java version like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date  = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, month, date);
long todayMillis2 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Printing the result using this:

```
System.out.println("Today is " + startOfToday);
System.out.println(todayMillis1);
System.out.println(todayMillis2);
```

will give you this output:

```
Today is 2016-08-03T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
1470196800000
1470196800000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows with **Calendar**:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
long millisecondsDate = date.getTimeInMillis();
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just as simple:

```
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
long ms = now.getTimeInMillis() - start.getTimeInMillis();
```

or:

```
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
long ms = now.getTimeInMillis() - new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).getTimeInMillis();
```